# Generators over semiperfect rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

It is clear that if $R$ is a ring with identity and $e\in R$ is an idempotent then $Re$ is a direct summand of $R$ while $R$ is a generator in the category of left $R$-modules. I have my question when $R$ is semiperfect: is $Re$ (isomorphic to) a direct summand of "every" generator of the left $R$-modules? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R=M_2(k)$ is the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field, then the $2$-dimensional left module of column vectors is a generator, but doesn't have $R$ (i.e., $Re$ for $e=1$) as a direct summand.

More generally, if $R$ contains any indecomposable projective module $P$ as a direct summand with multiplicity greater than one, then you can choose a generator $Q$ and an idempotent $e$ so that $Re$ contains $P$ with greater multiplicity than $Q$ does, so that $Re$ can't be a direct summand of $Q$.

Comment: If $e$ is a basic idempotent could the result hold? I mean if $e=e_1+...+e_n$ where $e_i$'s are pairwise orthogonal primitive idempotents (in the sense that each one is nonzero and could not be a sum of orthogonal idempotents) such that $Re_i$'s are a complete set of representatives of primitive left $R$-modules.

Comment: @karparvar Yes, it is known that if $e$ is a basic idempotent of a semiperfect ring, $eR$ is a summand of every generator of Mod-R. The first reference I dug up was in Faith & Page's *FPF ring theory*, Thm 1.2B.